# Deleted class still works - VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I wanted to implement a simple activation function to my C# application. It was something like this:

```
class Activation
{
    public Activation()
    {
        Some code...
    }
    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        Some code...
        string s = NumberOfDaysToExpire();
    }
}
```

The complete code is not a problem. The class sets some values to the Windows registry. I decided to launch the instance of this class in the main form's constructor and it worked fine.

The problem appeared when I decided to exclude this class from the project. The code shouldn't work but it still works !!! There is no declaration of this class in the whole project - so why does it still work ? I think this is a Visual Studio 2012 problem. Please help me.

Regards,

Mariusz

Comment: I guess there will be another class with same name. Select the class press F12, VS will take you where does it got the class from

Comment: build the project and classes again and try..!!

Comment: There is no other class with the same name. Anyway - thanks for your response. Rebuilding didn't help too...

Comment: What happened when you press F12 while the cursor is on that class?

Comment: Probably residual stuff left in the sdf file.  Close visual studio, delete the bin and obj directories.  Delete the .sdf file.  Restart VS and rebuild.  I get this all the time in C++.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees !!! The simpliest solutions are always the best :) Thank you very much.